# Java swing components not displayed properly outside netbeans

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

I have developed a Java Swing application. When running the application in Netbeans IDE, everything works properly (see http://www.fkserv.ugent.be/vrg/tom_dierickx/Screenshot2.png for a screenshot).

After building the project to .jar and running it in command line, the application window appears but the components are not displayed properly (See http://www.fkserv.ugent.be/vrg/tom_dierickx/Screenshot1.png for a screenshot).

Does anyone have experienced this before and may have a solution to this problem?

---

As the thread points out, this seems to be a Ubuntu-related problem. I experienced no trouble when running the application on a windows system.

Some threads on the web contribute the defect to Compiz or Beryl. However, I never installed these graphic-tools. However, I ran a line of code I found on the net for uninstalling Compiz. It seemed that Compiz was installed by default. Unfortunately, the problem remains. Beryl doesn't seem to be installed.

The threads also note to add `export AWT_TOOLKIT="MToolkit"`, but this doesn't seem to work either.

No runtime errors where generated on the command line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you run it? or are there any Exceptions on the command line?

Comment: Try turning off the Desktop Effects in Linux.

Comment: which version of Linux are you running it on? Are you using suns java version or openjdk?

Comment: How do you run the jar? What's in your classpath when running the jar? Is there alibrary included in your netbeans project that you missed when running your jar?

Comment: If you are going to use `MToolkit`, you have to have the motif library installed.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I came to following conclusions:

- The application runs on Windows, but not on Ubuntu.
- Some Swing applications run on Ubuntu, while others don't.

Hence it seems like the problem is due to one or a few Swing components which do not work in Ubuntu. I think it's best for now to avoid these components by testing what works and what does not.

Comment: try setting the theme from default theme to your native theme(using SystemLookAndFeel).